Livewire image upload returns 401
I'm trying to upload an image to CloudFlare from DigitalOcean's App platform with Laravel 10 and Livewire 3. I wrote a service for this and this service api was written according to CloudFlare's api document. My project runs smoothly on local, but on my production server, when I press the "Select File" button, mark the file, and then press the "Open" button, it gives an error. When I look at the console, I see the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()". What could be the problem with this and how can I solve it?
There are no error on logs and no error return to screen (APP_DEBUG=true).

You might need to add CSP headers to your requests to specify what your app accepts. I had the same issue as far as the error was concerned: strict-content-origin 401 error. It did not show up in laravel's logs for me. I only saw the error in the browser's dev tools.
See MDN's write up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy
I solved my issue by creating a middleware that adds the headers to each request. e.g. Here's a minimal implementation of what I mean:

php artisan make:middleware SecurityHeaders

For the handle function, rewrite it to add what you need, then pass the response along:
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    $cspValues = [
    "base-uri 'self'",
    "connect-src 'self'",
    "default-src 'self'",
    "img-src 'self' data:",
    "media-src 'self'",
    "object-src 'none'",
    "script-src 'self'",
    "style-src 'self'",
    "font-src 'self'"
    ];

    if (app()->isProduction()) {
        $response->headers->set('Content-Security-Policy', implode(";", $cspValues));
    }

    return $response;
}


Finally, add it in your routes file for the route(s) in question the way you would for any other middleware. I group my requests for this. e.g.
Route::middleware([SecurityHeaders::class])->group(function () {
    // your routes here
}




Is this secure though?
